# How can I save the current URL in a variable?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, chromium-embedded, tchromium

For minimize I use this code:

```
if (url = 'exiting.exit') then
Form1.Close;
```

When my app minimizes, the url changed. After restore, I need to load the previous url.
I want to save current URL to variable in my Delphi App with TChromium. How can I do this? In official docs I can't found what I need! I have no idea for this.

Comment: [`This way`](http://pastebin.com/9jinPn36) for instance.

Comment: @TLama: why don't you make an answer with the provided code? :)